# Mongoose: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on billing in node.js and I created a new Model `Stripecustomer` where I save the `stripe customer id` and this customer's `email`. I kinda copied the main code form my other mongoose models and changed it. I had hoped to instantly start using it but when I tried to find a document in this model I got the following error:

```
⛔️ Error:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
```

I have looked at it for half an hour and I can't see what I did wrong. Can anyone tell me where I did something wrong?

**workspace.controller.js: here is where I try to create a subscription. Stripecustomer is undefined, but I don't get why since I imported it on top**

```
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_dvebbZQPA4Vk8kKZaEuN32sD");
const {
  Group, User, Workspace, Stripecustomer
} = require('../models');
const { sendErr } = require('../../utils');



const billing = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const email = 'tijl.declerck@outlook.com';

    // get the payment plan
    const plan = await stripe.plans.retrieve('plan_EK1uRUJLJcDS6e');

    //   get the stripe customer or create a new one
      let customer;
    const existingCustomerDoc = await Stripecustomer.findOne({ email: email });

    // if we couldn't find an existing customer in our database...
    if (!existingCustomerDoc[0]) {
      // then we create a new customer
      customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email,
        source: 'src_18eYalAHEMiOZZp1l9ZTjSU0'
      });
    } else {
    //  we retrieve this customer in stripe
      customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(existingCustomerDoc.customer_id);
    }

    // subscribe the customer to the plan
    // You now have a customer subscribed to a plan.
    // Behind the scenes, Stripe creates an invoice for every billing cycle.
    // The invoice outlines what the customer owes, reflects when they will be or were charged, and tracks the payment status.
    // You can even add additional items to an invoice to factor in one-off charges like setup fees.
    const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
      customer: customer.id,
      items: [{ plan: plan.id }]
    });


    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'payment complete',
      obj: subscription
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return sendErr(res, err);
  }
};
```

**stripecustomer.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const stripeCustomerSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  customer_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const Stripecustomer = mongoose.model('Stripecustomer', stripeCustomerSchema);

module.exports = Stripecustomer;
```

Comment: I see you're requiring `../models`, but Stripecustomer is defined in a different file, `stripecustomer.model.js`. I don't see anything in your code that is actually loading `stripecustomer.model.js`. Can you share the contents of `../models.js`?

Comment: Did you try adding the callback within `findOne`? The mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) might be able to help further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably coming from ur models index.js file, can u share ur models/index.js file to make this more clear, because *findOne* is a mongoose function, if u get undefined it means `Stripecustome` is not an instance of a mongoose model

Comment: You were right, someone else made the backend and I wasn't aware of the index file. Thanks!